# Java: Nested recursive generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a set of classes that extend some base entity.  Classes in this set may also extend from each other creating a nested hierarchy.

My goal is for **all classes to have access to a method that creates a new instance of themselves**.  I want to implement this method in my base entity, so that all extending classes inherit this.

Here are three example classes defined to my pattern:

**BaseEntity.java**

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity> {

    Class<E> clazz;

    public BaseEntity(Class<E> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public E getNewInstance() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }

}
```

**Collection.java**

```
public class Collection<E extends Collection> extends BaseEntity<E> {

    public Collection() {
        super(Collection.class); 
        // compiler error: BaseEntity (java.lang.Class<E>) in BaseEntity cannot be applied to
        //                            (java.lang.Class<Collection>)
    }

    public Collection(Class<E> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

}
```

**Document.java**

```
public class Document extends Collection<Document> {

    public Document() {
        super(Document.class);
    }

}
```

With this setup, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Collection c = new Collection();
c = c.getNewInstance(); // compiler error

Document d = new Document();
d = d.getNewInstance();

Collection cd = new Document();
cd = cd.getNewInstance(); // compiler error
```

However note that there is a compiler error in the default constructor for `Collection.java`.  I'm not sure why this is being caused, and I think this is also causing the compiler errors in the sample main method.  What am I doing incorrectly and how do I resolve this?

Note that this a contrived example pertaining to a bigger problem I'm trying to solve.  I understand that this implementation by itself looks silly.

Comment: Conflicting names with a couple of popular java library classes causes confusion...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Collection<E...>` is a generic type, but your `Collection c` is a raw type. That means that *all* of its methods will be treated as raw types, which means they'll return the erasure of any generic that's there.

Your base class is declared as `BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity>`, which means that in this method:

```
E getNewInstance()
```

the erasure is

```
BaseEntity getNewInstance();
```

That means that `c.getNewInstance()` returns a `BaseEntity`, not a `Collection`, which is where your compilation error comes in.

`Document`, on the other hand, is *not* a generic class. That means that the erasure doesn't matter at compile time (for these purposes), and that `getNewInstance()` returns the type `E` represents, which in this case is `Document`. As such, `d.getNewInstance()` has a return type of `Document`, and so that line compiles fine.

---

As an aside: whenever you have recursive generics, you should make sure to account for the generic in the recursion. For instance, in this line:

```
BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity>
```

you've defined `BaseEntity` as a generic class -- but then immediately ignored its generic in `E extends BaseEntity`. That line should instead be:

```
BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity<E>>
```

Comment: Makes total sense, great explanation.  I think part of my problem is that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around recursive generics.  `BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity<E>>` is an example I have a hard time grasping.  But I'll just have to spend more time understanding, thanks again.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between `BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity<E>>` and `BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity<?>>` ?  They both seem valid ways to resolve recursive generics, but I've noticed differences in the way the compiler handles them.

Comment: That's a bit bigger than a comment -- it may be worth a followup question (I didn't find anything with "java recursive generics with wildcard"). But the difference is basically when your generic class itself uses methods on `E`. Consider if it had a method that took `E entity` and called `entity.getNewInstance()`. With `extends BaseEntity<E>`, you'd get back an `E`. With `extends BaseEntity<?>`, you'd get back a `BaseEntity<?>`.

Comment: there's no point here to do `BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity<E>>` over just `BaseEntity<E>`

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this constructor

```
public Collection() {
    super(Collection.class);
}
```

Is that the superclass constructor is expecting a `Class<E>`, but the class literal `Collection.class` is a `Class<Collection>`.  These types are incompatible, because `E` could be a `Collection`, a `Document`, or anything else that might extend `Collection`.

Any class like `Document` that extends `Collection` must supply its own class, so it will be calling the other `Collection` constructor that takes a `Class<E>` anyway, so I don't think the `Collection()` constructor has any use.  I would remove it.

Also, in your upper bound for `E`, you are using the raw form of the very classes you are attempting to make generic.  Use

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<E extends BaseEntity<E>> {
```

and

```
public class Collection<E extends Collection<E>> extends BaseEntity<E> {
```

The type `Collection` is generic, so you must specify the generic type parameter that matches the argument to the `Collection` constructor.

```
Collection<Document> c = new Collection<Document>(Document.class);
c = c.getNewInstance();
```

Document is not itself generic, so this code is still fine:

```
Document d = new Document();
d = d.getNewInstance();
```

`Document` must be supplied as a type argument to `Collection` even when directly creating a `Document`, because a `Document` is a `Collection<Document>`.

```
Collection<Document> cd = new Document();
cd = cd.getNewInstance();
```

Comment: Super helpful.  I understand the discrepancies in the main method.  One problem I'm still having is even after changing the class headers, I still have the same compiler error in my `Collection` default constructor

Comment: I think that the default constructor for `Collection` is useless.  I have recommended to remove it.  What good is a `Collection<Collection>`, when you must be after a concrete subclass?  Besides, that would force you to write `Collection<Collection<Collection>>`, which would force `Collection<Collection<Collection<Collection>>>`, and more levels of generics ad infinitum.